# W3C validator gives 'document type does not allow element "input" here...' error for XHTML

Tags: html, forms, xhtml, w3c-validation

I got this error when validating my page with W3C's validator.

[image: I got this error when validating my page with w3c's validator]

**Source:**

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<input type="text"/>
</form>
```

Can someone show me why I may have gotten this error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*This answer applies to XHTML, not HTML5.*

> The form and body element only accept
>   block level children `<form action="/">
>   <input type="submit"> </form>` … will
>   produce the error:
>
> document type does not allow element
>   "input" here; missing one of "p",
>   "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6",
>   "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset",
>   "ins", "del" start-tag.
>
> In Strict variants of (X)HTML, a form
>   element may have only block elements
>   as its children, but form controls
>   (such as input elements) are inline
>   elements. The solution is to pick a
>   block element with appropriate
>   semantics that may contain inline
>   elements; helpfully the validator
>   produces a list that can help you
>   narrow it down.
>
> When it comes to a form, appropriate
>   elements are usually fieldset or a
>   plain div.

[Source - Dorward Online](http://dorward.me.uk/www/element-not-allowed/)

So doing something like

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

will solve your problem.